# Intent's intended class can't read extended information from said intent

Tags: android

I am trying to send information from my main activity class to another class in my app package. The information is used to update an AlertDialog automatically. Here is the code I've been working with:

```
//This is in MainActivity.class
//Tests to see if SyncDialog will update itself with new intents.
public void testLoop() {
    int n = 0;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SyncDialog.class);
    while (n != 10) {
        intent.putExtra(TEST_NUMBER, n);
        n++;
    }
}

//This is in SyncDialog.class
//This method should get the int value from MainActivity
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    int n = intent.getIntExtra(TEST_NUMBER, 0);
    showNextDialog(n);
}
```

TEST_NUMBER is defined as a public constant at the top of MainActivity, and I even tried importing MainActivity into SyncDialog.class.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: make sure u have declared SyncDialog Activity as `android:launchMode="singleTask" `

Comment: If you're checking to see if altering the intent causes the changes to be seen in the other activity, I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make it a static constant if you want to access it in the way you are attempting. In MainActivity:

`public static String TEST_NUMBER = "test";`

and in SyncDialog:

`intent.getExtra(MainActivity.TEST_NUMBER, 0)`